# Type Families extension does not work as described

Tags: haskell, type-families

On [the Haskell wiki page for Type Families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families), there is the following list of examples:

```
type family F a :: *
type instance F [Int]              = Int         -- OK!
type instance F String             = Char        -- OK!
type instance F (F a)              = a           -- WRONG: type parameter mentions a type family
type instance F (forall a. (a, b)) = b           -- WRONG: a forall type appears in a type parameter
type instance F Float              = forall a.a  -- WRONG: right-hand side may not be a forall type
type instance where                              -- OK!
  F (Maybe Int)  = Int
  F (Maybe Bool) = Bool
  F (Maybe a)    = String
type instance where            -- WRONG: conflicts with earlier instances (see below)
  F Int = Float
  F a   = [a]

type family G a b :: * -> *
type instance G Int            = (,)     -- WRONG: must be two type parameters
type instance G Int Char Float = Double  -- WRONG: must be two type parameters
```

This demonstrates that `type instance where` is valid syntax under this extension. However the following code does not compile for me with GHC 7.4.2:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family F a :: *
type instance where
  F (Maybe Int)  = Int
  F (Maybe Bool) = Bool
  F (Maybe a)    = String
```

The error message is:

> test.hs:4:15: parse error on input `where'

Since this is a parsing error, it looks like that syntax is not supported, so am I missing a requisite extension, or is something else amiss?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be a case of premature documentation. According to [this blog post](http://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/ordered-overlapping-type-family-instances/), this syntax is part of a feature recently added to GHC HEAD, but it's not yet valid in any released version of GHC.

Comment: It seems that it is not premature documentation - it has been in GHC since January 2013. It is just that the latest release of the Haskell Platform (which is where my copy of GHC is from) only supplies the June 2012 version of GHC. I will just have to upgrade my GHC then. It would be nice if the wiki dated the features it describes.

Comment: @Dylan: The most recently released version of GHC is 7.6.3 from less than two weeks ago, and it's still not in there.

Comment: Ah, I naively assumed from the date of the blog post that the feature would therefore make it into the next version. Any ideas why it still isn't official? It seems like an extremely useful feature.

Comment: @Dylan: 7.6.3 was a bugfix release. The next significant version will be 7.8.1, which should include this feature and is planned for release late this year.

Comment: Since this [came up again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211822/ghc-7-10-2-type-families-extension-doesnt-work): This syntax was apparently retracted and never released. A similar feature with different syntax is now available for *closed* type families only.