# ghc 7.10.2 type families extension doesn't work

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

I'm getting `parse error on input ‘where’` when trying the following example in GHC 7.10.2:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family F a :: *
type instance where
  F (Maybe Int)  = Int
  F (Maybe Bool) = Bool
  F (Maybe a)    = String
```

[Same question was asked two years ago about GHC 7.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338175/type-families-extension-does-not-work-as-described).

I used type families fine with GHC 7.6.* (can't remember last digit) this year. Is it a problem with GHC 7.10.2?

According to [the User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/index.html), type families are available.

My GHC 7.10.2 and cabal 1.22.6.0 where installed from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type Families extension does not work as described](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338175/type-families-extension-does-not-work-as-described)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't mix open and closed type family syntax like this, and I'm not sure where you are getting that idea from. The correct syntax is

```
type family F a :: * where
  F (Maybe Int)  = Int
  F (Maybe Bool) = Bool
  F (Maybe a)    = String
```

Comment: Apparently the OP syntax *was* implemented for a while (in HEAD, not any released version), but [technical issues](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NewAxioms/ClosedTypeFamilies) led to it being retracted and replaced by the [current closed type family version only](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NewAxioms).